CORTEX-M jump causes UFSR=2
I have a binary file that is loaded to memory, where I need to make a call to function that is part of the binary myFunc. I know the declaration of the function as I have access to the C files,
custom_t myFunc(void* param, int size) . The function is supposed to be placed in location myFunc_PTR.
On my main code, I defined a type from that function typedef custom_t  (*myFunc_t)(void*, int)
Then I define the function at an address
myFunc_t myFunc = (myFunc_t) myFunc_PTR;
Finally, I call the function with
custom_t res = myFunc(void* someAddress, 1)
As I am on an RTL simulator, I can access all registers of the core, I could see that the PC value changes to the correct address as it gets the opcode, however, once that is received a UFSR is triggered with value 2 and means an invalid state (I could not understand much of what that means from ARM specifications).
Is what I am trying to achieve here doable? is there some mistake or setting that I might be missing?

I'll be blunt: voting to close this question is admitting to not knowing much about ARM MCUs... thus making one unqualified to cast a meaningful close vote. Don't vote to close just because you don't understand the question, unless it's clear that the question is meaningless. In this case, it clearly isn't - clearly to anyone who programmed on Cortex-M and did what the asker did, and got caught by the same problem. As is easy to do, obviously enough :)

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica vote to reopen it if you think it should be reversed

Let's look at ARM's AN209 "Using Cortex-M3/M4/M7 Fault Exceptions":

INVSTATE: [...] the processor has attempted to execute an instruction that makes illegal use of the Execution Program Status Register (EPSR). When this bit is set, the PC value stacked for the exception return points to the instruction that attempted the illegal use of the EPSR.
Potential reasons:
a) Loading a branch target address to PC with LSB=0.
b) Stacked PSR corrupted during exception or interrupt handling.
c) Vector table contains a vector address with LSB=0.

On those CPUs, the least significant bit (LSB) of PC controls the operating mode - ARM vs Thumb. Cortex-M processors do not support ARM mode instructions.
So, on those processors, the PC must be odd (LSB=1) at all times. The value of PC's LSB controls the operating mode only. The code must be halfword (16-bit) aligned and even though PC & 1 == 1, the actual code begins at an even address, as-if PC & 1 == 0.
C compilers will automatically set the LSB when an address of a function is taken. Since you're using an address that came from somewhere else, it doesn't have the LSB set.
The fix is to set the LSB of the address:
#include <stdint.h>

// This is for Cortex-M and/or for pointers to Thumb-mode
// functions.
//
// Use this function to convert the address of a function
// obtained from a generic memory block. Do not use with
// function pointers obtained by using & operator.

myFunc_t myFunc_cast(void* from) {
  intptr_t val = (intptr_t)from;
  assert((val & 1) == 0); // the code must be halfword-aligned
  val |= 1;
  return (myFunc_t)val;
}

myFunc_t myFunc = myFunc_cast(myFunc_PTR);

Per the C (and C++) standard, casting a function pointer to void* is undefined behavior, BUT on every mainstream embedded architecture it is implementation defined to work.
